# Выгрузка видео из памяти - QuartzTypeLib

Tags: c#

Проблема такая, есть программа, win form, на ней панелька, в которую показывает видео, видео файлы берутся из дирректории, считываются в массив и по кругу гоняются, класс показа видео (взят исходник с msdn и чуть переделан)

```
namespace MediaPlayer
{

    class MediaPly
    {
        internal const int
  WS_CHILD = 0x40000000,
  WS_VISIBLE = 0x10000000,
  LBS_NOTIFY = 0x00000001,
  HOST_ID = 0x00000002,
  LISTBOX_ID = 0x00000001,
  WS_VSCROLL = 0x00200000,
  WS_BORDER = 0x00800000;

        private FilgraphManagerClass graphManager = new QuartzTypeLib.FilgraphManagerClass();
        private IMediaControl mControl;
        private IMediaPosition mPosition;
        private IVideoWindow mWindow;
        public MediaPly()
        {
        }
        public bool LoadFile(string sfile, Panel parentHandler)
        {
            graphManager.RenderFile(sfile);
            mControl = graphManager;
            mPosition = graphManager;
            mWindow = graphManager;
            mWindow.Owner = parentHandler.Handle.ToInt32();
            mWindow.WindowStyle = WS_CHILD;
            mWindow.SetWindowPosition(parentHandler.ClientRectangle.Left,
                parentHandler.ClientRectangle.Top,
                parentHandler.ClientRectangle.Width,
                parentHandler.ClientRectangle.Height);

            graphManager.Run();
            return true;
        }

        public bool isStop()
        {
            if (graphManager.CurrentPosition == graphManager.Duration)
            {
                //graphManager.Stop();
                //graphManager.CurrentPosition = 0;
                return true;
            }
            else return false;
        }

        public string nowSec()
        {
            return graphManager.CurrentPosition.ToString();
        }

        public string allSec()
        {
            return graphManager.Duration.ToString();
        }

        public void setCurPos (double pos) 
        {
            graphManager.CurrentPosition = pos;
        }
    }
}
```

На форме :

```
MediaPly _mp = null;
public string filesPath = "video-files";
public string[] videofiles;
public int countFiles = 0;
public int playKey = 0;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {        
            this.Left = 0;
            this.Top = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height - this.Height;

            if (Directory.Exists(filesPath))
            {
                videofiles = Directory.GetFiles(filesPath);
                countFiles = videofiles.Count();
                if (File.Exists(videofiles[0]))
                {
                    _mp = new MediaPly();
                    _mp.LoadFile(videofiles[0], this.panel1);
                    timer1.Start();
                    //this.filePlay = fileName1;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("directory " + filesPath + " no exists");
            }

        }
     private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_mp.isStop())
            {
                //_mp.setCurPos(0.01);
                playKey++;
                if (playKey + 1 > countFiles) playKey = 0;
                _mp = new MediaPly();
                _mp.LoadFile(videofiles[playKey],this.panel1);
            }
            label1.Text = _mp.nowSec();
            label2.Text = _mp.allSec();
            label3.Text = videofiles[playKey] + " - " + playKey;
        }
```

собственно проблема такая, файлы крутятся по кругу, все почти нормально, но процесс в начале ~40mb в памяти, кручу 3 mp4 файла, показывает примерно 2-3 круга эти файлы и память вырастает до 150-160 mb, и потом сбрасывается обратно до 40, но проблема в том что когда она сбрасывается - 1 файл не показывает, т.е. стоит стоп толи последний кадр предъидущего файла, толи первый новово, я так понимаю когда память достигает предела, загружает новый файл и превышает место выделеное под процесс - память сбрасывается вместе с уже только что загруженым файлом и этот файл не показыват.... секунды идут что он воспроизводится но видео нет, после чего успешно проигрываются следущие файлы по кругу, и так опять несколько раз проиграет, затем память выростает и в тот момент когда она сбрасывается - опять не показывает один файл...
в C# я нуб, не понимаю особо как это работает, как происходит сброс памяти, может есть возможность както сбрасывать ее после каждого проиграного файла? или както еще решить этот вопрос

Comment: решилось так - 

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_mp.isStop())
        {
            //_mp.setCurPos(0.01);
            playKey++;
            if (playKey + 1 > countFiles) playKey = 0;
            _mp = new MediaPly();
            _mp.LoadFile(videofiles[playKey],this.panel1);
            GC.Collect();
        }
        label1.Text = _mp.nowSec();
        label2.Text = _mp.allSec();
        label3.Text = videofiles[playKey] + " - " + playKey;
    }

Comment: тобишь добавлением GC.Collect(); после загрузки очередного файла

Comment: Правильно, пофиг на освобождение памяти, пусть ГЦ вычищает тонны генерируемого мусора. Так и создается говнокод.

Comment: ну подскажите как сделать иначе? метода для графменеджера типо Finalise() или чтото в этом духе я не нашел, только Stop() который совершенно не решает проблемы